# Script works in spyder but not in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

After 2 weeks, my request to install anaconda at work finally got accepted and after small struggles with windows (coming from mac) I finally got my script working but now I can't seem to execute my script  outside of the spyder editor included in anaconda. I want to run my script over Anaconda Prompt but whenever I run the script I get the following error:

[image: Error Message]

Since the error already occurs in the first line I will spare you the rest of the code. But as mentioned before, the script works perfectly fine in spyder but causes an SyntaxError in anaconda prompt. The referenced cmd module is this one: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/cmd.html

Note: I tried pip installing cmd but couldn't. I am guessing because of my missing admin rights. Instead I just copied the code for the module into a py file into the folder of my project. It works completely fine in spyder.

Comment: That `cmd` is for Python 2.7, I think. Are you running it on Python 3?

Comment: (and why is it inside your `Tool` directory? Possibly Spyder is using the right one inside `\lib`?)

Comment: Yes, I am running it on Python 3 but it works in spyder & I've been using it in several projects running on python 3

Comment: Open Spyder, go to the `import cmd` line, highlight the word `cmd`, right-click and choose "go to definition". It will probably open the `cmd.py` you have under `\lib`, which should be for Python 3.

Comment: you were right. I mistakenly thought that cmd wasn't part of my distribution. Thanks a lot!